# Cannot find current proxy: Set 'exposeProxy' property on Advised to 'true' to make it available"

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop

I'm using `org.springframework.boot` version '2.3.3.RELEASE'.
When I'm running Integration tests on ProcessService class, I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find current proxy: Set 'exposeProxy' property on Advised to 'true' to make it available, and ensure that AopContext.currentProxy() is invoked in the same thread as the AOP invocation context.
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AopContext.currentProxy(AopContext.java:69)
```

This is the main class:

```
@EnableRetry
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedNotificationService
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy = true)
public class MainApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Service class getting the error:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class ProcessService {

@Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "${api.retry.limit}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${api.retry.max-interval}",
            multiplierExpression = "${api.retry.delay-multiplier}", maxDelayExpression = "${api.retry.max-delay}"))
public void triggerJob(Parameters...) throws Exception {
        // Some code
        method1();
        // some code
}

public JobResult method1(Parameters.. ) {
        ProcessService processService = (ProcessService) AopContext.currentProxy();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<JobResult> task = executorService.submit(() -> processService.method2(Parameters..));
        // some code
}

@Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "${api.retry.limit}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${api.retry.max-interval}",
            multiplierExpression = "${api.retry.delay-multiplier}", maxDelayExpression = "${api.retry.max-delay}"))
    JobResult method2(Parameters.. ) {
         // Some code
}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? How should I mock the `AopContext.currentProxy()` call in method1 to return an object of ProcessService class?
Currently, while test execution, the executon is stepping inside currentProxy() method of org.springframework.aop.framework.AopContext class and returning null.

```
public static Object currentProxy() throws IllegalStateException {
        Object proxy = currentProxy.get();
        if (proxy == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Cannot find current proxy: Set 'exposeProxy' property on Advised to 'true' to make it available, and " +
                            "ensure that AopContext.currentProxy() is invoked in the same thread as the AOP invocation context.");
        }
        return proxy;
}
```

Comment: Where is your integration test, pray tell? Can you please edit the question, either adding a link to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub or show more code (full classes, not just snippets) in order to make the problem reproducible? Does the application as such work outside of your integration test? Did the test work before, but not anymore after changes in the test code or after dependency version upgrades?

Answer (score 0):

In the Integration tests, I had to create a Mock static of AopContext and return the class.

```
@Mock
private MockedStatic<AopContext> aopContextMockedStatic;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
   MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
   processService = spy(new ProcessService(InputPraramters...));
aopContextMockedStatic.when(AopContext::currentProxy).thenReturn(processService);
}

@AfterEach
void tearDownStatic() {
    aopContextMockedStatic.close();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems **@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy = true)** [doesn't work](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16516#issuecomment-496533580) with **@EnableAsync** in Spring Boot

I created such a helper class to delegate my async operations

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AsyncHelper {

    @Async
    public <T> CompletableFuture<T> supplyAsync(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        log.info("supplyAsync invoked");
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier);
    }

    @Async
    public void runAsync(Runnable runnable) {
        log.info("runAsync invoked");
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(runnable);
    }
}
```

And now I removed @Async annotations from my target class and invoke helper instead like in this code:

```
protected CompletableFuture<String> doSupplyAsyncUsingHelper() {
    return asyncHelper.supplyAsync(() -> {
        doSomething();
        return "Something";
    });
}

protected void doRunAsyncUsingHelper() {
    asyncHelper.runAsync(() -> {
        doSomething();
        doSomethingElse();
    });
}
```